# how to display a QAbstractTableModel in python file in qml using pyQt

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, qml, pyqt5

I Created a QAbstactTableModel subclass and binded it with tableview in qml. I need to do the same with python file instead of c++. How can I do that. I don't know python well.                                                                 TableView.py

```
from os import path
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtProperty, QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtProperty, QCoreApplication, QObject, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtQml import qmlRegisterType, QQmlComponent, QQmlEngine, QQmlListProperty
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, pyqtSignal,pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlListProperty
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView
class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self.datatable = None

    def update(self, dataIn):
        print ('Updating Model')
        self.datatable = dataIn

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.datatable.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.datatable.columns.values)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            i = index.row()
            j = index.column()
            return '{0}'.format(self.datatable.iget_value(i, j))
        else:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
class MainWindow(QQuickView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.tablemodel=TableModel()
        self.rootContext().setContextProperty('PersonModel', self.tablemodel)
        self.rootContext().setContextProperty('MainWindow', self)
        self.setSource(QUrl('main.qml'))

myApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
ui = MainWindow()
ui.show()
sys.exit(myApp.exec_())
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TableView {
        id: idTableView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: PersonModel

        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("column count", columnCount)
            console.log("model column count", PersonModel.columnCount())

            for (var i = 0; i < PersonModel.columnCount(); i++)
            {
                var myTableViewColumn;
                var component = Qt.createComponent("MyTableViewColumn.qml")

                if (component.status === Component.Ready)
                {
                    myTableViewColumn = component.createObject();
                }

                if (null !== myTableViewColumn)
                {
                    console.log("add column")
                   // myTableViewColumn.role = dataModel.modelRoles[i]
                   // myTableViewColumn.title = dataModel.modelRoles[i]
                    idTableView.addColumn(myTableViewColumn)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Button {
        text: "click"
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        onClicked: {
            idTableView.addColumn(idColumnComponent)
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: idColumnComponent

        TableViewColumn {
            id: idColumn
        }
    }


}
```

When I run this code I am getting an error like   return len(self.datatable.index)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: Ok, so you want someone will write a code for you?

Comment: I am Sorry for the incomplete question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `datatable` is None so it has no columns or index (I do not know what type of structure is `datatable`), the solution is to set a size 0 for `rowCount()` and `columnCount()` if it is None otherwise we pass `index` or `columns`, respectively.

Another problem is that you should not use `QQuickView` since you are generating another topLevel besides the Window in the .qml so 2 windows will appear, you should only use `QQmlApplicationEngine`:

```
class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self.datatable = None

    def update(self, dataIn):
        print ('Updating Model')
        self.datatable = dataIn

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.datatable.index) if self.datatable else 0

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.datatable.columns.values) if self.datatable else 0

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            i = index.row()
            j = index.column()
            return '{0}'.format(self.datatable.iget_value(i, j))
        else:
            return QVariant()

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    myApp = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    tablemodel=TableModel()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('PersonModel', tablemodel)
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(QDir.current().absoluteFilePath('main.qml')))
    if len(engine.rootObjects()) == 0:
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(myApp.exec_())
```

Comment: My data table is an array of dictionary                                                                self.datatable = [
        { 'value1': 10, 'value2': 17, 'value3': 16, 'value4': 10},
        { 'value1': 11, 'value2': 13, 'value3': 17, 'value4': 16},
        { 'value1': 12, 'value2': 15, 'value3': 12, 'value4': 12},
        ]